# How to arrange continuous serial number in to two or multiple column sequentially in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, sequence, recursive-query

I want to print or display 1 to 10 or any max number in two column format using MS Sql-Server query.
Just like below attached screen shot image.

[image]

So please give any suggestion.

Comment: Will it always be 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this solution on it as below...

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity(1,1),
Number_1 int,
Number_2 int
)


declare @min int=1
declare @max int=10
declare @a int=0;
declare @id int=0


while(@min<=@max)
begin

if(@a=0)
begin
insert into @t
select @min,null
set @a=1
end
else if(@a=1)
begin
select top 1 @id=id from @t order by id desc
update @t set Number_2=@min where id=@id
set @a=0
end

set @min=@min+1
end

select Number_1,Number_2 from @t
```

Comment: Why a `WHILE`? SQL is a set based language; this would be the slowest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use recursive queries for this:

```
with cte (num1, num2) as (
    select 1, 2 
    union all
    select num1 + 2, num2 + 2 from cte where num2 < 10
)
select * from cte order by num1
```

You control the maximum number with the inequality condition in the recursive member of the cte.

If you need to generate more than 100 rows, you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of inline tallies would be way faster than a `WHILE`. This version will go up to 1000 integers (500 rows):

```sql
DECLARE @Start int = 1,
        @End int = 99;

SELECT TOP(CONVERT(int,CEILING(((@End*1.) - @Start + 1)/2)))
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1)*2 + @Start AS Number1,
       CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1)*2 + @Start +1 <= @End THEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1)*2 + @Start +1 END AS Number2
FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N1(N)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N2(N)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N3(N);
```

An alternative way that looks less messy with the `CASE` and `TOP` would be to use a couple of CTEs:

```sql
WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(@End - @Start + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 + @Start AS I
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N1(N)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N2(N)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N3(N)),
Numbers AS(
    SELECT I AS Number1,
           LEAD(I) OVER (ORDER BY I) AS Number2
    FROM Tally)
SELECT Number1,
       Number2
FROM Numbers 
WHERE Number1 % 2 = @Start % 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, set-based solution using window functions:

```sql
use tempdb

;with sample_data as (
select 1 as val union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6 union all
select 7 union all
select 8 union all
select 9 union all
select 10 
) 

, sample_data_split  as
(
    select 
        val
    ,   2- row_number() over (order by val) % 2 as columnid
    ,  NTILE((select count(*) / 2  from sample_data) ) over (order by val) groupid
    from sample_data
)
```

the intermediate result of `sample_data_split` is:

```sql
val columnid    groupid
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   1   2
4   2   2
5   1   3
6   2   3
7   1   4
8   2   4
9   1   5
10  2   5
```

and then to get the resultset into a desired format:

```sql
select 
    min(case when columnid = 1 then val end) as column1
,   min(case when columnid = 2 then val end) as column2
from sample_data_split
group by groupid
```

```sql
column1 column2
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
9   10
```

---

Those CTEs can be merged into a single SELECT:

```sql
select 
    min(case when columnid = 1 then val end) as column1
,   min(case when columnid = 2 then val end) as column2
from 
(
    select 
        val
    ,   2- row_number() over (order by val) % 2 as columnid
    ,  NTILE((select count(*) / 2  from sample_data) ) over (order by val) groupid
    from sample_data
) d
group by groupid
```

The positive side of a such approach, that it scales well and has no upper boundary on how much rows to be processed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are starting with a table with one column, you can use:

```
select min(number), max(number)
from sample_data
group by floor( (number - 1) / 2);
```